# A shader that casts shadows, doesn't receive shadows and doesn't render any textures/models at all?

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, shadows

Bit of a strange one but I'm in the situation where i need a shader to essentially render nothing and cast a shadow!

I found [this though some googling](https://forum.unity.com/threads/shader-for-displaying-self-shadow-without-rendering-the-actual-object.64941/#post-422023) but sadly that casts shadows onto itself which is undesirable.

Comment: This is [exposed as a property on the renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.html), so you don't need a custom shader for it.

Comment: That's awesome, did not know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by DMGregory, there is an option in the renderer to do this...

[image: Mesh Renderer]